# Could EF query be empty?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, interceptor

I have implemented **IDbCommandInterceptor** interface in my project. I want to make logging in its every function(ReaderExecuted, NonQueryExecuted, ...). The question is "Is there a situation, when **DbCommand command** is null?" In some examples on the net people using command?.CommandText, I want to be sure that this code wouldn't be a "dog-nail".

```
public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            Logger(command, interceptionContext);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so, at least not normally. The [DbCommand class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) contains its own (non-static) execution methods, and [DbConnection does *not*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection?view=netframework-4.7.2), so you need an instance of DbCommand to trigger the (I)DbCommandInterceptor handlers normally. That said, IDbCommandInterceptor is just an interface, and anyone who had a reference to the interceptor could manually invoke any of its public methods with a null argument. It depends on how well-behaved you expect people consuming your code to be.